# Raymarching on a Hi-Z buffer in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, raycasting, depth-buffer

So I'm trying to implement Screen Space Reflections using a Hierarchical z-Buffer in GLSL. I'm following the approach from GPU Gems 5 and the Frostbite presentation [linked here](http://advances.realtimerendering.com/s2015/index.html) ("Stochastic Screen-Space Reflections", Slide 36+).

I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding how the algorithm works, however there are not many information about this algorithm, besides of the resources I linked.

My current GLSL code looks like this:

```
vec3 trace_ray(vec3 ray_start, vec3 ray_dir)
{

    ray_dir = normalize(ray_dir);
    ivec2 work_size = SCREEN_SIZE_INT;
    const int loop_max = 250;
    int mipmap = 0;
    int max_iter = loop_max;
    vec3 pos = ray_start;

    // Move pos by a small bias to avoid self-intersection
    pos += ray_dir * 0.004;
    float hit_bias = 0.002;

    while (mipmap > -1 && max_iter --> 0)
    {

        // Check if we are out of screen bounds, if so, return
        if (pos.x < 0.0 || pos.y < 0.0 || pos.x > 1.0 || pos.y > 1.0 || pos.z < 0.0 || pos.z > 1.0)
        {
            return vec3(0,0,0);
        }

        // Compute the fractional part of the coordinate (scaled by the working size)
        // so the values will be between 0.0 and 1.0
        vec2 fract_coord = mod(pos.xy * work_size, 1.0);

        // Modify fract coord based on which direction we are stepping in.
        // Fract coord now contains the percentage how far we moved already in
        // the current cell in each direction.  
        fract_coord.x = ray_dir.x > 0.0 ? fract_coord.x : 1.0 - fract_coord.x;
        fract_coord.y = ray_dir.y > 0.0 ? fract_coord.y : 1.0 - fract_coord.y;

        // Compute maximum k for which the ray would still be inside of the cell.
        float max_k_x = (1.0 / ray_dir.x) / work_size.x;
        float max_k_y = (1.0 / ray_dir.y) / work_size.y;

        // Scale the maximum k by the percentage we already processed in the current cell,
        // since e.g. if we already moved 50%, we can only move another 50%.
        max_k_x *= 1.0 - fract_coord.x;
        max_k_y *= 1.0 - fract_coord.y;

        // The maximum k is the minimum of the both sub-k's since if once maximum
        // is reached, the ray is out of the cell
        float max_k = min(abs(max_k_x), abs(max_k_y) );

        // Fetch the current minimum cell plane height
        float cell_z = textureLod(DownscaledDepth, pos.xy, mipmap).x;

        // Check if the ray intersects with the cell plane. We have the following
        // equation: 
        // pos.z + k * ray_dir.z = cell.z
        // So k is:
        float k = (cell_z - pos.z) / ray_dir.z;

        // Check if we intersected the cell
        if (k > 0.0 && k < max_k + hit_bias )
        {
            // Move to point of intersection    
            pos += k * ray_dir;

            // In case we are at mipmap level 0, we found a match
            if (mipmap == 0) {
                return pos;
            }

            // If we hit anything at a higher mipmap, step up to a higher detailed
            // mipmap:
            mipmap -= 2;
            work_size *= 4;
        }

        // If we hit nothing, move to the next cell, with a small bias
        pos += max_k * ray_dir * 1.02;

        mipmap += 1;
        work_size /= 2;

    }
    return vec3(0);
}
```

And the result is:
[image]

So I'm doing something wrong, its probably not much since the result is not completely off, however, I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**TL;DR: Am I either misunderstanding how the Algorithm works, or if not, what am I missing or doing wrong in my code?**

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured the error now, I thought I'd share the code I used so others can benefit from it:

```
vec3 trace_ray(vec3 ray_start, vec3 ray_dir)
{

    if (ray_dir.z < 0.0) {
        return vec3(0);
    }

    ray_dir = normalize(ray_dir);
    ivec2 work_size = SCREEN_SIZE_INT;

    const int loop_max = 150;
    int mipmap = 0;
    int max_iter = loop_max;

    vec3 pos = ray_start;

    // Move pos by a small bias
    pos += ray_dir * 0.008;

    float hit_bias = 0.0017;

    while (mipmap > -1 && max_iter --> 0)
    {

        // Check if we are out of screen bounds, if so, return
        if (pos.x < 0.0 || pos.y < 0.0 || pos.x > 1.0 || pos.y > 1.0 || pos.z < 0.0 || pos.z > 1.0)
        {
            return vec3(0,0,0);
        }

        // Fetch the current minimum cell plane height
        float cell_z = textureLod(DownscaledDepth, pos.xy, mipmap).x;

        // Compute the fractional part of the coordinate (scaled by the working size)
        // so the values will be between 0.0 and 1.0
        vec2 fract_coord = mod(pos.xy * work_size, 1.0);

        // Modify fract coord based on which direction we are stepping in.
        // Fract coord now contains the percentage how far we moved already in
        // the current cell in each direction.  
        fract_coord.x = ray_dir.x > 0.0 ? fract_coord.x : 1.0 - fract_coord.x;
        fract_coord.y = ray_dir.y > 0.0 ? fract_coord.y : 1.0 - fract_coord.y;

        // Compute maximum k and minimum k for which the ray would still be
        // inside of the cell.
        vec2 max_k_v = (1.0 / abs(ray_dir.xy)) / work_size.xy;
        vec2 min_k_v = -max_k_v * fract_coord.xy;

        // Scale the maximum k by the percentage we already processed in the current cell,
        // since e.g. if we already moved 50%, we can only move another 50%.
        max_k_v *= 1.0 - fract_coord.xy;

        // The maximum k is the minimum of the both sub-k's since if one component-maximum
        // is reached, the ray is out of the cell
        float max_k = min(max_k_v.x, max_k_v.y);

        // Same applies to the min_k, but because min_k is negative we have to use max()
        float min_k = max(min_k_v.x, min_k_v.y);

        // Check if the ray intersects with the cell plane. We have the following
        // equation: 
        // pos.z + k * ray_dir.z = cell.z
        // So k is:
        float k = (cell_z - pos.z) / ray_dir.z;

        // Optional: Abort when ray didn't exactly intersect:
        // if (k < min_k && mipmap <= 0) {
        //     return vec3(0);
        // } 

        // Check if we intersected the cell
        if (k < max_k + hit_bias)
        {
            // Clamp k
            k = max(min_k, k);

            if (mipmap < 1) {
                pos += k * ray_dir;
                return pos;
            }

            // If we hit anything at a higher mipmap, step up to a higher detailed
            // mipmap:
            mipmap -= 2;
            work_size *= 4;
        } else {

            // If we hit nothing, move to the next cell, with a small bias
            pos += max_k * ray_dir * 1.04;
        }

        mipmap += 1;
        work_size /= 2;
    }

    return vec3(0);
}
```

Result:

[image: Result Image]

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included a summary of what changed, from the version above & why, so readers don't need to do a line-by-line diff to follow your line of thinking.